# How to use Google Cloud Build with Yarn 2+

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, google-cloud-build, yarnpkg-v2

How do I use Google Cloud Build with Yarn 2+? Do I need to create my own node image to support this or is there some shorthanded entrypoint like `entrypoint: "yarn2"`

Cloud Build with NodeJs:

```
steps:
  - name: "node"
    entrypoint: "yarn"
```

Currently results in:

```
Step #0: Pulling image: node
Step #0: Using default tag: latest
...
Step #0: yarn run v1.22.19
```

Comment: Have you checked this [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/217593036) and [Github issue link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/buildpacks/issues/175#issuecomment-1030519240) wherein it is suggested to use Yarn 2's PnP mode as Yarn 2 is not yet fully supported on Cloud Build?

Comment: I see, I must have missed somewhere the information that Yarn2 is not supported yet officially. Would be nice if they included that in their Cloud Build docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as a community wiki, as per previous comment, Yarn 2 is not yet fully supported on Google Cloud Build. It is suggested to use Yarn 2's PnP mode based on these documentation posted in [Google Cloud feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/217593036) and [Github issue link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/buildpacks/issues/175#issuecomment-1030519240).

Answer (score 1):

I am using Cloud Storage to store Yarn v2 cache in a compressed file. I switched from using `--cache-from` functionality from Cloud Build to this method and the build time has decreased from ~3 min to ~1.5min

```yaml
steps:
  - id: 'download-cached-yarn-dependencies'
    name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
    entrypoint: bash
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        gsutil cp gs://my-cache-bucket/my-app.cache.tgz build-cache.tgz || exit 0
        tar -zxf build-cache.tgz || exit 0

  - id: 'install-dependencies'
    name: node:16
    entrypoint: bash
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        yarn config set enableGlobalCache true
        yarn config set globalFolder .yarn-cache
        yarn install --immutable

  - id: 'upload-cached-yarn-dependencies'
    name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
    entrypoint: bash
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        tar -zcf build-cache.tgz .yarn-cache
        gsutil cp build-cache.tgz gs://my-cache-bucket/my-app.cache.tgz
```

Comment: I'm getting the error `.yarn-cache: Cannot stat: No such file or directory`. Are you creating that directory somehow?

Comment: It's created during the Docker build. This is the RUN command I use for it: 
 ```RUN yarn config set enableGlobalCache true && \
    yarn config set globalFolder .yarn-cache && \
    yarn install --immutable```